# How can we enable encryption for a particular folder in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created a S3 bucket.I want to encrypt a  objects inside a specific folder in S3 bucket.How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [We have](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingEncryption.html) **Server-Side Encryption** and **Client-Side Encryption**
- Protecting Data Using Server-Side Encryption You have three mutually exclusive options depending on how you choose to manage the encryption keys [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/serv-side-encryption.html)
- Use Server-Side Encryption with Amazon S3-Managed Keys (SSE-S3)
- Use Server-Side Encryption with Keys Stored in AWS KMS (SSE-KMS)
- Use Server-Side Encryption with Customer-Provided Keys (SSE-C)

  **Protecting Data Using Server-Side Encryption** (**SSE-S3**)
- You can set the policy on the specific bucket to only allow encrypted data in for all the objects inside that bucket [aws doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingServerSideEncryption.html)
- Note in your case for S3 policy would be like this assuming this as the bucket structure `outbound/globalscape/dlearn`.
- Go on to the aws console--> click on outbound folder --> and then on permissions --> bucket policy --> and paste the below policy and save

  **S3 policy for the bucket**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "PutObjPolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DenyIncorrectEncryptionHeader",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::outbound/globalscape/dlearn/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::outbound/globalscape/dlearn/*",
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- The bucket policy denies permissions to upload an object unless the request includes the **x-amz-server-side-encryption** header to request server-side encryption.

```
"s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
```

- **This aws blog** [How to Prevent Uploads of Unencrypted Objects to Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-prevent-uploads-of-unencrypted-objects-to-amazon-s3/) which is basically doing the same to check go to  (**Implementing use case #1: Using SSE-S3 managed keys**) in the blog.
- In the above blog go to **Testing the solutions** where in they are using Policy Simulator to test. There as well the user policy which they have given you will have to replace this bit `"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::outbound/globalscape/dlearn/*"` object in the image attached again has to be your bucket `arn:aws:s3:::outbound/globalscape/dlearn/`.
- you can then test it once keeping the value `AES256` and once keeping it blank.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer.Can we use the bucket policy to encrypt specific folder in S3 bucket?@amittn

Comment: @UdayTej  as the docs have a policy which can be used, just replace your bucket name there https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingServerSideEncryption.html

Comment: @amittin I have applied below policy for encryption by  reffering the documentation.I have S3 bucket name-->outbound(folder)-->globalscape(folder)-->dlearn(folder).But i need files under dlearn folder to  be encrypted by  default.When im  uploading file there.It is not encrypting by  default

Comment: @UdayTej Go on to the aws console--> click on outbound folder --> and then on permissions --> bucket policy -->
out there change the  `"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::outbound/globalscape/dlearn/*",` save it and it should work

Comment: @UdayTej I have update the ans and also added testing method if you need any help let me know

Comment: @amittin Thanks much.Your solution is working when  we upload a file and select encryption for a particular file.But can  it encrpt by  default at rest if we are not selecting encryption.Becuase we are running lambda batch job to  upload the files in S3 and in code we are not encrypting it.

Comment: @UdayTej Server-side encryption protects data at rest.The x-amz-server-side-encryption header to request server-side encryption.

Comment: @UdayTej If the ans has helped you. can you please accept the ans

Comment: @admittin can we please write for me the policy  like withou selecting the encryption key while uploading. The file should be encrypted at rest by default.

Comment: Thanks much. This policy and type of answering the question are really  good @amittn

Answer (score 1):

[Encrypting a folder using the Amazon S3 console](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-encrypt-specific-folder/)

> 1. Open the Amazon S3 console.
> 2. Navigate to the folder that you want to encrypt.
> 3. Select the folder, and then choose Actions.
> 4. Choose Change encryption.
> 5. For Change encryption, select AWS-KMS.
> 6. For Select a key, select the AWS KMS key that you want to encrypt the folder with.
> 7. Choose Save.

Comment: Juned Ahsan Thank you for the answer.I have tried the above steps.But when a new file uploads through lambda batch to S3 that is not encrypted.How can we do it by default for a particular folder not to bucket?

Comment: The verbiage you're looking for in step 4 is now "Edit server-side encryption"